# <button> no submitting form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that I have tied to some JS that is disabling the button and changing the text to 'Loading...' once clicked, then the APIs go to work(around 12-15 seconds). However when I click the button it just says 'Loading..' and the form doesn't submit, to clarify nothing is happening besides the button changing. Preferably I'd like to use 'input' but with that the form submits but the button doesn't change. I am no JS expert so any help is great. Thanks.

```
<button id="fat-btn" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-block">Get Quotes</button>




    <script>
        $(function(){
            var $btn = $('#fat-btn');
            $btn.click(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.attr('disabled', 'disabled').html("Loading...");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $this.removeAttr('disabled').html('Get Quotes');
                }, 3000)
                document.getElementById("fat-btn").submit();
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: is your button inside form tag ?

Comment: yes, its definitely within the tags.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the ID of the form to submit. Not the id of the button.

Comment: he hasn't forms because button submits  without javascript

Comment: besides, dom object itself don't have submit() method

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of what I'm doing here? Seems like if I did that then the button would no longer change to the 'Loading...' state.

Comment: Not if the button is outside of the form or you stop the default event from occurring.

Comment: This question is right. If you want to submit the form, you need to target the form. When you are submitting the form, the page reloads. You will not see the button change because the page is submitting and it will be set to what the next page has set. That is how form submissions work.

Comment: The form takes a while. Upwards of 10 seconds that's why I want it to say loading so people don't click the button 2 millions times things that its not loading.

Comment: There's lots of ways to disable this. Just disabling the button after the first press would be a great start.

Comment: The button does everything I want it to besides submit. The text changes and the button gets disabled. The only thing I need it to do is submit the form. Which its not doing.